# SQL to list can't compare list correctly JAVA

Tags: java, list

I have an SQL query that bring up a string, I add that string into a list, and want to compare the result of that list, so that i can check the duplicates in said list

```
String q = "SELECT SURROGATE,sibling_surrogate,WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER FROM ppoltran";
List<List> resultSet = sqlCore.sqlExecuteQuery(q);
System.out.println("There are " + resultSet.size() + " transactions to be corrected.");
for (List list : resultSet) {
    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

This is the result I get from the print

```
[[SURROGATE] = [547476849], [sibling_surrogate] = [1038309665], [WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER] = [4]]
[[SURROGATE] = [1038282064], [sibling_surrogate] = [1038282065], [WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER] = [0]]
[[SURROGATE] = [547476849], [sibling_surrogate] = [1038284155], [WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER] = [0]]
[[SURROGATE] = [1038273562], [sibling_surrogate] = [1038286005], [WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER] = [1]]
```

What I want to do is to compare from the same `Surrogate`, when the `WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER` repeats and save the `sibling_surrogate` of that results. So i want to detect the Item that have the same `Surrogate`same `WINS_SEQUENCE_NUMBER`

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: I edited the question but even now I can't figure out what you're asking. Can you please re-edit and clarify what you want?

Comment: can yopu help me understand what is it that you dont understand? i have a string result from the SQL query, and i put that result on the list, i want to compare those result with each other to see if i have any duplicant in the Surrogate and Wins_Sequence_Number

Comment: I think you may have to use `regex` to achieve this.

Comment: Can you use Java 8 ?

Comment: No, i can't use Java 8

Comment: You can either use a `GROUP BY` in your SQL request to achieve this

Comment: no, i think i can't use group by, because you need all the data interconected in the same row

Comment: Use `Group BY` to structure the data, you can then merge the results with some Java code. I think it is also possible in pure SQL but this really isn't my strong point